# InputStream and BufferedReader

Tags: java, c#, socket.io, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm doing a chat application between mulitples clients in C# who connects a single Java Server.

So I send a message by one of users to the server, and the server sends this message to all others connected users.

Each client has a different Thread in the server, and in the thread I have;

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {

private Server server;
private Socket sck;

InputStream receive;
OutputStream send;

public ServerThread(Server server, Socket s) {
    this.server = server;
    sck = s;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        handleClient();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void handleClient() throws IOException {
    receive = sck.getInputStream();
    send = sck.getOutputStream();

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    receive.read(b);
    System.out.print(new String(b));

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receive, "UTF-8"));
    String line;

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))break;
        List<ServerThread> clients = server.getClients();
        for(ServerThread allClients : clients) {
            allClients.send(line);
        }
    }
}

private void send(String message) {
    try {
        send.write(message.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And my problem is:

when a client send something to the server, I can read it with;

```
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
receive.read(b);
System.out.print(new String(b));
```

I get the correct String I sent, but the BufferedReader doesnt receive anything. 
The program never goes into the while loop because

```
line = reader.readLine();
```

doesnt read anything, so I dont have any idea what's wrong. Why "InputStream#read(byte)" works but "BufferedReader#readLine()" doesnt work.. ?

Here is what I send by the C# app;

```
byte[] text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF-8.GetBytes("test1212");
sck.Send(text);
```

Is something wrong with this message? :v

EDIT:
Even with "\r\n" at the end of the message I send the Buffered doesnt read it.. How i'm supposed to add the carriage return to the message?

Hope somebody find what's wrong.

Thanks for trying to help me.
(Sorry if i made mistakes, I'm French :l)

Comment: I don't know what exactly the C# part does, but `readLine` expects a line, that is, some text followed by a newline character (or end of stream) - Doc: "Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), a carriage return followed immediately by a line feed, or by reaching the end-of-file (EOF)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read javadoc: [BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--)

"... Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed. ..."

Your line does not have end of line. BufferedReader waits for it.